# Angular model bound select box not displaying hard coded placeholder

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

I am loading some ajax data into a select element using `ng-repeat`. When the data (postcodeAddresses) is available it displays the select box. When a select box option is clicked it should call a function and wipe the array of data.

This all works, but as soon as a select option is selected, the input select is updated to the value then wiped clean leaving an empty box. It is not visible in the select box but is displayed in the dom with no changes.

In theory what I need is to refresh the select element to its original state when the page loaded.

I have tried these to reset the placeholder but none work:

```
$('select.postcode').prop('selected', function() {
     return this.defaultSelected;
});

$('select.postcode').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

Has anyone got ideas how I can get the options placeholder to be visible after clicking an option and resetting data?

```
<div ng-show="postcodeAddresses.length > 0" class="postcode-select">
    <select class="form-input form-select postcode" ng-model="selectedAddress.address" ng-change="updateAddressFields('address')">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden >Select address...</option>
        <option ng-repeat="address in postcodeAddresses" value="@{{$index}}">@{{address.line_1}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably because you are using `hidden` attribute for the default option.

Comment: This hides the option from displaying inside the option list/dropdown. It still displays correctly using hidden inside the select input on page load just not after a options is selected.